# Pseudo-Random number generation in lua. Variable loop issues

Tags: random, lua, numbers, random-seed

Alright, someone must know easier ways to do this than me. 
I'm trying to write a random number generator using a fairly common formula.

```
--Random Number Generator
local X0=os.time() 
local A1=710425941047
local B1=813633012810
local M1=711719770602
local X1=(((A1*X0)+B1)%M1)

local X2=(((A1*X1)+B1)%M1) --then I basically take the vaiable X1 and feed 
                           --it back into itself.
print(X2)
local X3=(((A1*X2)+B1)%M1)
print(X3)
local X4=(((A1*X3)+B1)%M1)
print(X4)
local X5=(((A1*X4)+B1)%M1)
print(X5)
local X6=(((A1*X5)+B1)%M1)
print(X6)
local X7=(((A1*X6)+B1)%M1)
print(X7)
```

Etc Etc.
Does anybody know a faster way to do this? 
I would love to be able to fit it into something along the lines of a:

```
for i=1,Number do
    local X[loop count]=(((A1*X[Loop count-1])+B1)%M1)
    math.randomseed(X[loop count])
    local roll=math.random(1,20)
    print("You rolled a "..roll)
end
io.read()
```

Type of string.
I'm using it to generate random numbers for pieces of track I'm making in a tabletop game.
Example hunk of code:

```
if trackclass == "S" then
for i=1,S do     --Stated earlier that S=25
    local roll=math.random(1,5)
    local SP=math.random(1,3)
    local Count= roll
    if Count == 1 then
        local Track = "Straightaway"
        p(Track.." Of SP "..SP)
        else
    end
    if Count == 2 then
        local Track = "Curve"
        p(Track.." of SP "..SP)
        else
    end
    if Count == 3 then
        local Track = "Hill"
        p(Track.." of SP "..SP)
        else
    end
    if Count == 4 then
        local Track = "Water"
        p(Track.." of SP "..SP)
        else
    end
    if Count == 5 then
        local Track = "Jump"
        p(Track.." of SP "..SP)
        else
    end
end
```

end

Unfortunately this seems to generate a pretty poor set of random number distribution when I use it and I would really like it to work out better. Any possible assistance in fleshing out the variable loop cycle would be greatly appreciated.
Even something like a call so that every time math.random() is called, it adds one to the X[loop count]] so that every generated number is actually a better pseudo-random number distribution.

Please forgive my semi-rambling. My mind is not necessarily thinking in order right now.

Comment: What's wrong with Lua's built-in `math.random` and `math.randomseed`?

Comment: Mostly because math.randomseed() needs an input variable for the seed. But, for every math.random(1,20) a single seed will always output the same variable continuously. Ie. 13,13,13,13,13... So therefore, I'm trying to generate a new seed in a semi-continuous long-repeating circle so as to be able to go for hundreds of generations without calling the same set of numbers again.

Comment: Why are you re-seeding the random number generator each time you use it? You don't need to; just seed it with `os.time()` when the program starts and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know a faster way to do this?

Each X<sup>N</sup> in the expression is always the previous X, so just restructure the code to use the previous X rather than creating new ones:

```
local X = os.time() 
local A1 = 710425941047
local B1 = 813633012810
local M1 = 711719770602

function myrandomseed(val)
    X = val
end

function myrandom()
    X = (A1 * X + B1) % M1
    return X
end
```

Now you can call `myrandom` to your heart's content:

```
for i=1,100 do
    print(myrandom())
end
```

Another way of packaging it, to avoid static scope, would be generating random number generators as closures, which bind to their state variables:

```
function getrandom(seed)
    local X = seed or os.time()
    local A1 = 710425941047
    local B1 = 813633012810
    local M1 = 711719770602
    return function()
        X = (A1 * X + B1) % M1
        return X
    end
end
```

Now you call `getrandom` to get a random number generator for a given seed:

```
local rand = getrandom()
for i=1,100 do
    print(rand())
end
```

---

> I would love to be able to fit it into something along the lines of a:
>          math.randomseed(X[loop count])
>          local roll=math.random(1,20)

If you're calling randomseed every time you call random, you're not using Lua's (i.e. C's) random number generator at all. You can see why this is true by looking at `myrandomseed` above. Why are you funneling your numbers through Lua's random in the first place? Why not just use `math.random` and be done with it.

Just make to sure to call `math.randomseed` once rather than every time you call `math.random` and you'll be fine.

---

> I'm using it to generate random numbers for pieces of track I'm making in a tabletop game. Example hunk of code:

When you see tons of nearly identical code, you should refactor it. When you see variables names like `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. you're either naming variables poorly or should be using a list. In your case you have a bunch of branches `Count == 1`, `Count == 2`, etc. when we could be using a list. For instance, this does the same thing as your code:

```
local trackTypes = { 'Straightaway', 'Curve', 'Hill', 'Water', 'Jump' }
for i=1,S do 
    local trackTypeIndex = math.random(1, #trackTypes)
    local SP = math.random(1, 3)
    p(trackTypes[trackTypeIndex]..' of SP '..SP)
end
```

Note that you can probably guess what `trackTypes` is just by reading the variable name. I have no idea what `S` and `SP` are. They are probably not good names.

Comment: After some playing I see what you're talking about now. The way I wanted to do it was going to result in me always getting the same series of random numbers. Setting     math.randomseed(os.time()) at the beginning just gave me a better array of random, I was just misusing it before because I understood less about it resulting in more unneeded work.